# AlarmManager only lets one Service through when used with setRepeating in Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. What I want to do is run a service periodically, about 2-3 minutes apart. I have an Activity that is responsible for the interface and setting up the first alarm.

The alarm is configured by a BroadcastReceiver which looks like this:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          String message = "Alarm worked";
          Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          setAlarm(context);
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.
                              getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
                              0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, DiscoveryService.class);
        context.startService(dailyUpdater);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() 
                              + (1000 * 30) , pi);
    }
}
```

I've tried using setRepeating for AlarmManager, but it still has the same effect. What happens is that the AlarmManager works how it should, it fires an Intent which the receiver gets and executes onReceive periodically, as it should. However, it executes the service only the first time. After the first time, the alarms still go off, but the service is not executed.

I read some threads from people with similar problems, and one of them mentioned that PendingIntent lasts for only one send. Thus, I opted out to setting the alarm every time so I can set pendingIntent flag for updating every time.

I tried making my service an intentService, which is fine, but then my bluetooth scanner inside the service does not work because intentService thread terminates without waiting for my bluetooth discovery to finish.

Anyone have any idea what can help me?

Here is part of my service:

```
public class DiscoveryService extends Service {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        findEverything();
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the code that I currently have.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String message = "Alarm worked";
      Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, DiscoveryService.class);
      context.startService(dailyUpdater);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context){
    // get a Calendar object with current time
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context. 
                             getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                             (1000 * 30) , pi);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens is that the AlarmManager works how it should, it fires an Intent which the reciever gets and executes onReceive periodically, as it should. However, it executes the service only the first time. After the first time, the alarms still go off, but the service is not executed.

You are calling `startService()` once when you are *scheduling* the alarm. You are *not* calling `startService()` *at all* from your `BroadcastReceiver`. Yet you are scheduling the alarm via the `BroadcastReceiver`. Hence, when the alarm goes off, the service will not be sent a command, because you are not sending it a command.

> I read some threads from people with similar problems, and one of them mentioned that PendingIntent lasts for only one send.

That is only if you use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

> Anyone have any idea what can help me?

Call `startService()` from your `onReceive()` method, instead of from your `setAlarm()` method. Also, add in all the `WakeLock` management logic, since you are using a `_WAKEUP` alarm and you are not able to use my `WakefulIntentService`.

Comment: Well, I had the startService() in the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver, with a setRepeating when I start the alarm. The effect it the same, it fires off one service and then never again.

Comment: @user2116291: Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see when your alarm is next scheduled to go off. Also, add in the `WakeLock` logic that you are missing, as your service may not get invoked at your expected time without it.

Comment: My alarm goes off. I've tested it. It goes off every 30 seconds as specified, it just doesn't start the service.

Thanks for taking your time out of your day to answer this.

Comment: @user2116291: "it just doesn't start the service" -- then either you do not have the `startService()` call in `onReceive()`, or you are passing it the wrong `Intent` (one that does not identify the service). The latter should show up as some warnings in LogCat.

Comment: I added my current code to my post. I send toasts every time the alarm goes off, and I see toasts every 30 seconds as a result of that. That tells me that the AlarmService is working, and it does execute onReceive, but it only starts the service on the first time. LogCat doesn't give any warnings or wrong intents.

Comment: @user2116291: That's because your service isn't doing anything. `onCreate()` is called when the service is *created*. If you are not stopping the service, the service will *continue running*. If you want to do something every time `startService()` is called, you need to implement `onStartCommand()`, instead of (or in addition to) `onCreate()`.

Comment: I have added the onStartCommand(), I've put a toast to indicate its execution, but it does not execute. Should I be passing in an intent parameter to onStartCommand?

Comment: @user2116291: You should be reading the documentation for `onStartCommand()`. http://goo.gl/qqtzu `onStartCommand()` takes three parameters, including an `Intent`. You also should add `@Override` annotations on all methods where you think you are overriding a superclass method (or implementing a method defined on an interface), so that the compiler will let you know when you have an incorrect method signature.

Comment: Yes, I looked up the specs for onStartCommand() and it finally worked. Thank you very much for your help. I apologize for the multitude of questions!